# Invalid Syntax when adding Conv1D to CNN model definition

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, text-classification

I'm trying to use CNN for text classification (Using Keras). In most tutorials, they suggest using `Conv1D` for that, but when I try to define the model, I get an `Invalid Syntax` error.

These are the libraries I'm importing:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
```

This is the model definition:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 32, input_length=max_length)

model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu')) #This is where I'm getting the error
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

This is the error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-29-a0d7dea5e2b2>", line 3
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu'))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you tell me what did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a bracket:

```
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 32, input_length=max_length) ) <----
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo